# Terminal-specific font settings

Tags: command-line, fonts

Since sharp fonts are better for my eyes, I use the MS fonts with full hinting and no anti-aliasing, system wide. It works great for all applications, but the terminal. I've found no fixed-width font that looks acceptable so far. Is there a way to set font hinting to slight and turn on anti-aliasing *only* for the terminal?

(I'm using a 13.04 daily build with Unity, if this matters.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not related to my problem. I know how to set the terminal font, but it won't let me specify the smoothing/anti-aliasing settings, it uses the global settings.

Answer (score 5):

As `gnome-terminal` doesn't really have the configuration options you require, you will need to use a more configurable terminal emulator such as `rxvt-unicode` (`urxvt`), which allows you to change just about everything possible, including individual font hinting and anti-aliasing settings.

```
sudo apt-get install rxvt-unicode
```

After you have installed it, it can be run as `urxvt`. You must create an `~/.Xresources` file in your home folder and specify all your settings there (or `~/.Xdefaults` can be used instead). After editing that file each time you must run

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

so that the settings take effect and you can use the terminal with those new settings straight-away when it is restarted. If occasionally this does not clear `urxvt` settings properly and reload your new ones, logout and login again.

The [urxvt manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/urxvt.1.html) is just full of information that explains how to configure your terminal, but we will concentrate on the font settings here, as that is what you are interested in.

All options in your `~/.Xresources` file are often specified in this basic format:

```
URxvt.option:value
```

although there will often be a number of variations on that pattern, as noted [in this piece about urxvt configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rxvt-unicode).

Find the list of fonts installed in your system with `fc-list`, or glance at gnome-terminal's list for reference. There are some good examples of font configuration [in this article](http://wiki.afterstep.org/index.php?title=Rxvt-Unicode_Configuration_Tutorial). A modified example from that article is similar to my setup (except that I have `antialias=false`):

```
URxvt.font:xft:Ubuntu Mono:pixelsize=14:antialias=true:hinting=true:hintsyle=hintslight  
URxvt.boldFont:xft:Ubuntu Mono:bold:pixelsize=14:antialias=true:hinting=true:hintsyle=hintslight
```

These lines should go in your `~/.Xresources` file along with all your other customisations.

There are many more possibilities (DejaVu Sans Mono is a good font as well), but this example specifies the font options you wanted such as anti-aliasing and hinting. It should get you started on developing your own `urxvt` configuration. Be aware that some fonts might not display correctly in `urxvt`, and perhaps not all fonts on your system are [xft fonts](http://www.keithp.com/~keithp/render/Xft.tutorial), although you can only specify the options you want with xft fonts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gnome-terminal, you can adjust the font by clicking `Edit->Profile Preferences` in the menu bar. Uncheck "Use the system fixed width font" and then you can set the font used in the terminal emulator.

Comment: This changes the font, but does not allow you to specify per font xft options such as hinting and anti-aliasing that the OP wants.